# Mounting docker volume using rexray driver in GCE fails

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, docker-volume

I have been trying to create docker volume using [RexRay](https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) driver in GCE VM instance following the steps mentioned at http://collabnix.com/building-persistent-storage-solution-with-dellemc-rexray-0-8-docker-17-03-managed-plugin-system-for-cloud-platforms/

Here the rexray is installed and enabled as docker plugin.
I am stuck at volume creation step. The command for the same is as below:

```
sudo docker volume create --driver rexray/gcepd --name storage1 --opt=size=32
```

Below is the error I am receiving executing the command:

```
Error response from daemon: create storage1: VolumeDriver.Create: docker-legacy: Create: storage1: failed: error querying for existing volume
```

Could not find anything on the web for the above error string.

I got the same error while I was trying the same steps in VM instance with Container Optimized OS.

Below are further details of my setup:

- GCE instance with Debian OS
- Instance Service account with Project Editor permission
- Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me, I was able to create a volume on my project. 
Your instance should have the storage scopes as read and write, to do, you need to stop the instance and edit the details on **Cloud API access scopes** or you can select **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs** and save.

After restart your instance and SSH run the below command line:

```
$ sudo docker volume create --driver rexray/gcepd --opt size=50 --name test-volume
```

Container Optimized OS have some limitation and the kernel is not enabled.

Comment: That was access scopes issue. Marked your solution as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Just an update: It also works with Container Optimized OS.